# Purchased horses refuse to wait

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I purchased a horse in Skyrim, and he simply refuses to wait for me. At first I thought it was because I was near a city. But even in the wildest part of Tamriel, it still trots away whenever I stop riding him. I tried with another horse, same thing. They basically act like wild horses when I gave hardly and honestly (kinda) gained money for them. It's not due to any mods, I started a game without any and still the same thing.

So yeah... Any idea how to fix that bug?

Comment: Are you sure you mounted the right horse? That's the behavior of stolen horses.

Comment: Yeah it *is* the right horse, no doubt on that.

Comment: `Since Patch 1.6, any horse you have bought that gets killed will eventually respawn and head back to the stables. A respawned horse can be mounted and ridden, but will start to walk towards its stables as soon as you dismount. You can still buy new horses even though the respawned ones are at the stables. It is possible to have multiple respawned horses at the same stable. This makes it difficult to identify your newest horse that hasn't died yet.` http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Horses#Bugs

Comment: Nope. Not that. The going back to the stable thing started as soon as I got my first horse. And when I buy a new one I get the same problem before the horse even get a chance to be killed off as well. So it can't be a respawning problem.

Comment: Follow it for a bit. I seem to remember mine trotting off on me whenever I dismounted, but it would always stop after a short little walk. I don't know if this is what's happening, but that is just what I remember.

Comment: Where did you buy your horse from? I had issues with the Riften horses walking away from me but not others. I think my issue was related to doing the quest for helping the stable hand and the horses there stopped being marked as Steal.

Comment: Just for grins - try this: save your game first, then kill your horse, then go and buy a new horse and see if the problem occurs with it as well. I remember running into some funky behavior with horses at the stables near Solitude, where the game thought I'd stolen the horse even though I was 100% certain it was mine. I think the issue resolved itself once I got a different horse.

Comment: (forgot to check this for a while. Sorry) I recently bought another horse from my Steward and the problem and this time the horse stay where I leave him. The only problem is the horses related mods I downloaded don't work with it. But anyway I'd very much like have one of the Solitude horse instead. Ravekner: Tried that, it leaded me a stable, far away from where we were. Biff Magriff: I've tried with basically all the horses, always the same. Jagd: Changing horses doesn't really resolve anything (well except for the steward one, but I don't really like it :/).

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, you cannot get horses to wait. But, you *can* go to [Katla's farm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Katla%27s_Farm), pick her wheat and sell it back to her. You will then be able to take the horses from her stable for free. These horses will NOT be owned by the player and will walk back to their home (Katla's farm) when you dismount.

Take one, (for free), kill that horse, (being the one that follows you), then no horse will follow you.